# custom module in user

Tags: 7, debugging

I am making a custom module and the link to the path appears on navigation menu by default but I am interested it appears on primary menu when module is enabled. Is it possible in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `menu_name` key of your menu-router item. From [the docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7):

> **menu_name:** Optional. Set this to a custom menu if you don't want your item to be placed in Navigation.

By default the primary links are set to the *Main menu* (machine name: `main-menu`). Therefore use something like this in your implementation of `hook_menu`:

```
function hook_menu() {
  $items['example'] = array(
    'title' => 'Example Page',
    'page callback' => 'example_page',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
  );
  return $items;
}
```